# Changing Visual Studio Code Theme Colors

Tags: colors, themes, visual-studio-code

I'm using the Atom One Dark theme extension for Visual Studio Code, but I'd like to change the color of variable types and constant names. I've circled those elements in white in this image.

[image: image]]

Is there any json code that I could use to change the colors of the variable types and constant names? I've tried using the following code, but it doesn't seem to change anything in the editor, much less those elements:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Atom One Dark]": {
            "variables": "#FF0000",
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                  "scope": "variable",
                  "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic",
                    "foreground": "#C69650"
                  }
                }
              ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes, you're doing it right... maybe raise a user voice/github reaction.